# How to inherit style from another component?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I want to take styling from the component 'Tab' which is a react-router-dom **Navlink** and apply it to my new component 'DropdownTab' which is a 'div'. How can I inherit the styling without making it a NavLink? I want to do this to avoid duplicate lines of code.

```
const Tab = styled(NavLink)`
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: ${variables.height};
  line-height: ${variables.height};
`;

// Should be the component 'Menu' and is now the component NavLink
const DropdownTab = styled(Tab)`
`;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you can use [`as`](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#as-polymorphic-prop)?

```
const DropdownTab = styled(props => <Tab as="div" {...props} />)`
  /* additional styles */
`;
```

That's ugly though, so maybe you can just extract the common styles into a variable:

```
const commonStyles = `
  /* common styles */
`

const Tab = styled(NavLink)`${commonStyles}`
const DropdownTab = styled('div')`${commonStyles}`
```

If you have prop-based style in your component (i.e `color: ${props => props.color}`, you'd need to use `css` helper:

```
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components'

const commonStyles = css`
  color: ${({ isActive }) => isActive ? 'red' : 'blue' };
`

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is `DropdownTab` a `div`?

Based on your code, `DropdownTab` is a `Tab`. You've used the [extending styles](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#extending-styles) concept of styled-components and **you've done it right**.